# Is it better to check values before passing to a library function, or catch a thrown exception?

Tags: c++, exception

Say I'm using a library that has a function `to_int` that takes a string parameter. This function returns an int if the string is a character representation of a number, e.g `"23"` would return `23`. If the string isn't a number it throws an `std::runtime_error`. Would it be better to:

```
if(is_all_digits(str))
    x = to_int(str);
else
    output("not an int, idiot. Try again");
```

Or

```
try 
{
    x = to_int(str);
}
catch(...)
{
    output("not an int, idiot. Try again");
}
```

Comment: what is better? better == faster? less code? less binary size? easier to read code?

Comment: Is `is_all_digits`/`is_valid_int` part of the library ?

Answer (score 2):

There are several different error handling techniques and each have advantages and disadvantages.

Lets consider a function `getAllElements()` which gets a container with some elements.

Now this may produce an error (database connection or whatever). You now have the options

```
Errorcode getAllElements(std::vector<...> & cont);
```

or

```
std::vector<...> getAllElements(); //throws exceptions
```

It is kind of a general design question usually and depends on circumstances. I prefer the one with the exceptions for multiple reasons. I can just assign and don't need a predetermined container

```
auto elements = getAllElements();
```

The next thing is where will you handle your errors? If you handle them like 5 functions above in the stack you have to check for the error-code every time and just give it to the next function. An exception will automatically propagate until someone catches it and is able to deal with it.

---

Exceptions though have some disadvantage. They cause a bigger binary and is slower when an exception gets thrown. In game development usually no exceptions are used because of that ( Listen to this for more info on that: http://cppcast.com/2016/10/guy-davidson/ they talk about why not using exceptions. I don't have the timestamp currently though. )

Also exceptions should be used in exceptional cases. Errors you cannot deal with immediately and have to be dealt with somewhere higher.

---

So if you don't need high performance / a small binary I would suggest using exceptions where they are useful. They can result in typing less code (like checking return codes) which can result in less places for introducing bugs.

Here is also a good discussion on error handling mechanisms from CppCon 2016: 
[CppCon 2016: Patrice Roy “The Exception Situation"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Fno6suiXLPs&list=PLHTh1InhhwT7J5jl4vAhO1WvGHUUFgUQH&index=42)

Answer (score 1):

There is no single answer to this question, as it depends on how the program as a whole can deal with bad input, and whether it can sensibly recover when errors are detected (regardless of whether those errors are reported using return codes or by throwing exceptions).

Can every function which calls `to_int()` recover from bad input immediately?   If not, it is better to allow an exception to be thrown .... so it unwinds the stack until there is some caller (with a `try/catch` block) that can actually recover from the error.

What if you have numerous functions that call `to_int()`, do you want to do the check in every one?    If so, this results in a lot of code duplication.

What if you have some function that calls `to_int()` which can recover immediately from the error and some others that cannot?

What if you want to report an error to the caller (e.g. to allow something more substantial than writing an error string)?

What is there is no `is_all_digits()` function?   If there is not, what if you implement it in a way that misses some errors that `to_int()` will detect?   Then you have the worst of both worlds - doing the error checking in an attempt to prevent an exception being thrown, but then the function throwing an exception anyway.  For example, there might be some global setting that causes `to_int()` to only accept octal digits (in range `0` to `7`), but your `is_all_digits()` function deems all decimal digits to be valid.

More generally, the real need is to define an error handling strategy that works for your program as a whole.   Trying to decide, based on usage of a single function, between throwing exceptions or not throwing exceptions, is completely missing the point.

If it makes sense for your program to report errors using exceptions (e.g. with a single centralised `try/catch` block in `main()` so all errors propagate up the call stack so `main()` implements the recovery globally) then throw exceptions.     If it makes sense for every function in your program to detect errors and silently deal with them on the spot, then avoid exceptions.

What I'm advocating is allow the dog (your program) to wag the tail (low level decisions on how to handle errors).    Your question is essentially asking if it is appropriate to allow the tail to wag the dog.

Answer (score 0):

If the caught exception is really specific than you can use a specific try catch (using a generic try catch is not a good idea since you are hiding a bunch of other possible errors)

Generically speaking my preference is to check the string before passing it to the function.

Answer (score 0):

When you are using a library or an API you want it to prevent you from bad usages and  other mistakes.

This is the role of your function to control the integrity of the given parameters, and to throw an exception.

Note that you can also use assertions when developing your code, and then disable it for binary production.